# About lock of some document from DB

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have question about C# programming.
I`ll describe the problem below and I hope to understand me.
C# WPF app

In my software can login 2 persons with different accounts. User1 and User2.
I want when User1 open some document from SQL DB (Doc with ID=5) for editing, the second User2 to have opportunity only to open and to see the document but without rights to Edit.

Case: When User1 who already editing the doc. with ID = 5, receive internet connection problem or electricity problem and the connection between SQL and his machine is canceled.

HOW the software will know about this and to UNLOCK the document ID = 5 to be enable to be edited from another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you have a datetime property in your database 'DocumentLockedAt'.  Then your logic for deciding if a document is locked is basedon this field instead of a binary 1/0 (that way you can choose to ignore locks older than 1 hour etc).

If you need finer control you can periodically UPDATE 'DocumentLockedAt' from your client application while you know it is still in use.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. What about Sinagletone pattern? I can lock the document and when somebody try to open again the same document to be possible but with disable fields. But is it this Singleton will UNLOCK automatically the document when the User1 have problem with connection or electricity?

Comment: You can't do anything in your client software to affect the database once the connection has been closed.  The best you can do is record when you fetched the document and make a sensible decision about when to override the lock status based on this field (e.g. after an hour has expired with no edits to the document).